# Set image as wallpaper , lock screen, wait screen

Tags: android

I want implements code android to set image as wallpaper , lock screen, wait screen from url:

[image: display as]

Answer (score 1):

**To set a Wallpaper to the Lockscreen use the new flag WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK, and one of the methods which take int which**

*WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setStream(inputStream, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);*

**You can also use one of the following methods**

*int setStream (InputStream bitmapData,  Rect visibleCropHint,  boolean allowBackup, int which)*

*int setResource (int resid, int which)*

*int setBitmap (Bitmap fullImage, Rect visibleCropHint,  boolean allowBackup,  int which)*

Answer (score 0):

public void SetBackground(int Url) {

```
try {
    File file = new File("/sdcard/sampleimage");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), Url);
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, new FileOutputStream(file));
    Context context = this.getBaseContext();
    context.setWallpaper(bitmap);            
 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

As the lockscreen wallpaper is not editable on Android, this is not possible from the offcial tools.

Comment: Thanks for answered, but it don't open dialog "set as" option home screen, lock screen...